# Get child element by name using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have below xml string

```
<Folder>
        <name></name>
        <Placemark>
            <name></name>
            <description></description>
            <styleUrl></styleUrl>
            <MultiGeometry>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates></coordinates>
                </Point>
                <LineString>
                    <coordinates></coordinates>
                    <tesselate>1</tesselate>
                </LineString>
            </MultiGeometry>
        </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Using XElement, is there any way to pull **Point** element from the xml string without having to traverse through it's parent node? (**MultiGeometry**)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "traverse through its parent node", and why do you want to avoid doing that?

Comment: yes, see : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mtqjm5

Comment: @EdPlunkett reason is, xml string can have different structure, with Point element in any position.

Answer (score 9):

If the data is loaded into a valid XElement you can use [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.

```
var xElement = XElement.Load(path);
var points = xElement.Descendants("Point");
var point = points.FirstOrDefault();
```